# Find All Consecutive Dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble figuring out a query to only display consecutive dates (minimum 3) in SQL. After searching stack exchange, there are a few solutions but I can't get them to work exactly how I want it to. Consider the following table (actual data and table names changed for security):

```
code         food         date   
------       ------      ------
ABC123       Sushi       09/28/2013
ABC123       Sushi       09/29/2013
ABC123       Sushi       09/30/2013
ABC123       Sushi       10/01/2013
BCD234       Burger      10/05/2013
BCD234       Burger      10/10/2013
BCD234       Burger      10/27/2013
BCD234       Fries       10/05/2013
BCD234       Fries       10/06/2013
BCD234       Fries       10/10/2013
CDE345       Steak       10/15/2013
CDE345       Steak       10/16/2013
CDE345       Steak       10/17/2013
CDE345       Steak       10/19/2013
CDE345       Steak       10/20/2013
DEF456       Pasta       09/05/2013
DEF456       Pasta       09/06/2013
DEF456       Pasta       09/10/2013
DEF456       Burrito     09/09/2013
DEF456       Burrito     09/10/2013
DEF456       Burrito     09/11/2013
```

Only this should be displayed:

```
code         food         date   
------       ------      ------
ABC123       Sushi       09/28/2013
ABC123       Sushi       09/29/2013
ABC123       Sushi       09/30/2013
ABC123       Sushi       10/01/2013
CDE345       Steak       10/15/2013
CDE345       Steak       10/16/2013
CDE345       Steak       10/17/2013
DEF456       Burrito     09/09/2013
DEF456       Burrito     09/10/2013
DEF456       Burrito     09/11/2013
```

Considering that the code, food, and date are all variable at any given time, what would be the query to create a result as shown above? The query should only find minimum 3 consecutive dates for each given code and food pair (key).

I tried messing around with one of the queries on Stack Exchange:

```
select code, grp, count(*) as NumInSequence, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*, (date - row_number() over (partition by code order by date)) as grp
  from #TempTable t
    ) t
group by code, grp
```

...but I get an error regarding converting data type varchar to bigint (which is probably due to the code being alphanumeric as opposed to just a regular int ID). Also, I am assuming that the above code wouldn't give me the exact result anyway.

Please advise, and thank you for your help.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm slow today but it's not clear how yo uwent from the first table to the 2nd (more compressed) table

Comment: ah it's `minimum 3 consecutive dates for each given code and food pair (key)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using window functions.  You can identify groups of consecutive dates by subtracting `row_number()` from the date.  With the group, you can then count the number of rows, and choose only those that have 3 or more rows:

```
select code, food, date
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by code, food, grp) as cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   dateadd(day, - row_number() over (partition by code, food order by date), date) as grp
            from #temptable t
           ) t
     ) t
where cnt >= 3;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I tested this out and the results came up empty.

Comment: This could happen if, for instance, your dates had time components.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: @misosouper . . . Store your date as a `date` and it will work . . . http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5d5b/3.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Looks like it works great! If the table is a temporary table though, how do I cast the date column entries to "date"? For example, let's say the result set is put into a temporary table #TempTable. Would I have to use Convert( or Cast( somewhere in the query, or before it gets inserted into a temporary table?

Comment: You can use `convert()` with the appropriate format argument.

Comment: the example works great, but I am now trying to apply it to the actual data. However I can't get it to work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81e4e/2 . The "grp" column is showing numbers instead of dates, why is that?

Comment: @misosouper . . . The original version of the answer had `datesub()` rather than `dateadd()`.  `dateadd()` is the right function and should result in a date.

Answer (score 0):

```
    you can create temp table with two additional columns
    columns-id (identify(1,1) and delta_date.
    and insert into it the 'old table'.
    the column 'delta_date' is results of date(column2)-date(column1) by day
    (and so for all rows respectively).
    now you can select all rows where 'delta_date'=1 and count 'delta_date'>=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple change to your original code should make it work:

```
select code, FOOD,grp, count(*) as NumInSequence, min([date]) AS MIN_date, max([date]) AS MAX_Date
from (select CODE,FOOD,[DATE],(DATEDIFF(D,'1/1/1900',[date])) - row_number() over (partition by code,FOOD order by [date]) as grp from @T t ) t
group by code, FOOD, grp 
HAVING count(*) >= 3
order by code
```

By converting the inner date to an int via days from some base date '1/1/1900', an int value is created that can now be used within your existing code!
Additionally I added Food Group to the row_number() section to find only matches that also include the user/Item Combo.